# Is there a Java stream method for finding the average value for a specific field property which is inside a list of Objects?

Tags: java, list, object, java-stream, average

I have a list which stores objects from the class Vehicle:

```
List< Vehicle > vehicles= new ArrayList<>();
```

The class vehicle has property "type"(of type String) and property "horsepower"(of type Double).

I find the average car horse power like this:

```
double averageCarHorsePower = average(vehicles.stream.filter(e -> e.getType().equals("car")).collect(Collectors.toList()));

private static double average (List< Vehicle > vehicles) { `
    if (vehicles.size() == 0) 
        return 0.0;
    }
    double sum = 0;
    for (Vehicle vehicle : vehicles) {
        sum += vehicle.getHorsepower();
    }
    return sum / vehicles.size();
```

But I want to find the average in one line without using a method.

I am asking this kind of question, because with Array stream it is simply:

```
double average = Array.stream(vehiclesHorsepower).mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue().average();
```

Comment: `vehicles.stream().mapToDouble(Vehicle::getHorsepower).average()`??

Comment: I'm kinda lost, what is the question here?

Comment: And note: do not use the ">" quote char to show code. Just indent with 4 spaces, or select it and click the `{}` button.

Comment: @Naman The question sits only in the TITLE, it isnt repeated i the body.

Comment: @Slaw it is not that easy. Because I have to filter between two type of Models, trucks and cars.

Comment: @МетодиВладимиров `vehicles.stream().filter("filter vehicles here").mapToDouble(Vehicle::getHorsepower).average()` then. You have used both the `filter` and `map` operation in the existing attempt. Just merge into a single solution.

Comment: "I have to filter between the two type of Models" - what's the problem with adding the filter to the stream? You're actually doing that already (`average(vehicles.stream.filter(...))`) so just combine the 2 approaches.

Comment: @Naman I am writting this: vehicles.stream().filter(e -> e.getType().equals("car")).mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).average(); and It says "Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: @GhostCatsaysReinstateMonica Thanks. I did read the title as well. But the body, already has a lot of code that OP could make use of to conclude an answer.

Comment: @МетодиВладимиров Did you notice `mapToDouble(Vehicle::getHorsepower)` instead of `mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)`?

Comment: Then simply add a `filter` operation to the stream pipeline. If you want to calculate the average horsepower for each model type in one go, then look at the different collectors available in the [`Collectors`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) class; you'll want to use `groupingBy` with a downstream of `averagingDouble`.

Comment: @Naman Yes, but now it says - Required: double, Found: java.util.OptionalDouble ..

Comment: Yes, because `DoubleStream#average()` returns an `OptionalDouble`, [as documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#average()). The optional will be empty if the stream was empty. What value do you want to return if there is no average? For an example, let's say `0`; then you'd simply do `...average().orElse(0)`.

Comment: @Slaw Thank you very much, Sir! I have a lot more to learn.

Comment: @Naman Why not to work?  It simply iterates between all objects in the filtered list and takes all horse power values.

Answer (score 3):

**Collectors.averagingDouble** Calculates the average value of a Double
property of the items in the stream.

```
double averageCarHorsePower = vehicles.stream()
         .filter(v -> v.getType().equals("cars"))
         .collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(Vehicle::getHorsePower));
```